# Precision and Scale max limits for Float and Double precision types in SqlServer

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, scale, precision, sqldatatypes

What are the limits of the precision and scale for Float and Double datatypes.Float allows scale of max value of, what are the restrictions for it.suppose if we give Float(19) but still it can store values having scale like (2555555.55555555).
and what is the max precision and scale limit for Double Precision Type.

Thanks in advance.